# IE doesn't set cookie when return File() from ActionResult

Tags: .net, file, internet-explorer, cookies, actionresult

So I have a problem with a cookie not setting after returning a File only happening in IE.

The logic is as follows:

1. When use first visits the page they are returned a View
2. User submits the form and a document is generated
   2.a. If the generation of the file succeeds: it returns a file for the user to download.
   2.b. If the generation of the file fails: it returns an error message.

In both cases of **2**: the page should show a message because of a cookie being set - however it only shows a message when the file fails and not when it returns a file for download.

My code looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string parm) {
    if (parm != null) {
        // generate file and message
        byte[] generatedFile = GenerateCsvFile(parm, out bool success, out string message);

        // Set cookie with message saying it failed or succeeded
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("downloadedFile", message) {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60)
        });

        if (success) { // return file for user to download
            return File(generatedFile, "text/csv", "MyDocument.csv");
        }
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(204); // do nothing because it failed
    }

    // Initial view load
    return View();
}
```

What is happening here and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code that what value is contained by the message when it get succeed or failed? also try to check the code from where this message get set it's value may help to find the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Your direction helped me figure it out. There was an invalid character in the cookie so I needed to URL Encode it first - it then worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result message when a file was returned included characters that were invalid to put into a cookie readable by IE (but readable by Chrome, Firefox etc).
Therefore the fix was to URL encode it before setting it as the cookie.

```
Response.Cookies.Add(
    new HttpCookie("downloadedFile", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message)) {
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60)
    });
```